# Why do i get an error when running my discord.py code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, discord.py

I always get this error code when I run my discord.py bot.
this is the error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_ready() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

This is the link to my full code:

https://pastebin.com/wVftj2kF

I ran my bot before changing the "on-ready" event to include 'self' and it worked. Removing 'self' breaks the "self.user" part of the command. I need help quick. Thanks a lot if you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually need to refer to self outside of a class in order to retrieve attributes of the bot, you can just use client.

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    change_status.start()
    print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(client.user))
```